# How do I create a managed package with SFDX?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, force-cli

I am trying to create a managed package using SFDX CLI.

I am executing a command

```
sfdx force:package:create -n name -t Managed -r force-app
```

but receiving an error

> ERROR:  You must specify a namespace for this package.

When I change `sfdx-project.json` to include namespace, I receive another error

```
$ sfdx force:package:create -n name -t Managed -r force-app
```

> ERROR:  The specified namespace is not owned by the dev hub.

I don't understand this error message.

How do I own specified namespace by Dev Hub?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, looks like I have to create Developer Edition org and register a namespace there and then link it to my Dev Hub org due to documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm

Comment: You are correct. Once you do that, you can then create scratch orgs with that managed package.